# Cannot redeclare function previously declared, declared only once

Tags: php

I'm running into a problem including this function from another file

```
function sendRes($s_attachment) //this is line 3
{
   /*Snip : processing message details..*/

    try {
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        logMessage("An error occured:" . $e->getMessage());
    }
} //this is line 54
```

When running the script, it outputs the following error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sendRes() (previously declared in
>   **********\email.php:3) in ***********\email.php on line 54

But it's declared only once, I checked that the file is included only once too. And the file contains only this function.

Any clues about why this isn't working ?

Comment: Can you post both line 3 and line 54 in that file?

Comment: you're using require "email.php" in multiple parts? it will great if you try using require_once in all those instances instead.

Comment: Agreed. Instances where you pull in email.php you should replace with `require_once`.

Comment: I'm using it only once, the reason I put it in a seperate file is to keep my original file clean as this function uses  a lot of local strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

remove the block of code you included and see what the code below returns.

`var_dump(function_exists('send_res'));`

If you get false, you're including the file with that function twice, replace:

`include` with `include_once` and replace `require` with `require_once`.

Another alternative, put your code in this if statement like this:

```
if (!function_exists('sendRes')) {
    function sendRes($s_attachment) //this is line 3
    {
        /*Snip : processing message details..*/

        try {
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            logMessage("An error occured Sending fingerprint:" . $e->getMessage());
        }
    } //this is line 54
}
```

Comment: You sir deserve a beer. Although no idea where the second include comes from, this worked. I'll investigate it further later, but for now, this is my answer ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it with

```
if(function_exists('function_name')) {

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

Comment: The function you're looking for is `function_exists` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php